# WP7 database choice SQLite or SQL Server CE

Tags: database, sqlite, windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

I'm developing windows phone 7 app. We are using sqlite database in android version.

I've found some answers here that we should use SQL Server CE now that Mango supports it, but I failed to find any performance comparison.

I only managed to find that SQLite is faster and smaller, and SQL Server CE is easier to implement in .NET.

Did anyone make performance comparison?

Any other reason behind using SQL Server CE?

My tables contain few strings and some thumbnails stored as byte[]. One of the features is dynamic search based on keyboard input, thats why im so concerned about performance.

Comment: I haven't seen any speed comparisons but, from what I've seen, Windows Phone 8 works better with SQLite than WP7 (it also goes well with Windows 8 store apps) ... supposedly you can get WP7 to use it. What sort of data usage scenarios are you looking for comparisons on?  how big are your tables?

Comment: Really is SQLite more realiable than SQL CE? would never expect that. Added information about tables to question

Comment: The IT-3000 is nearly 10 years old. Hardware has changed a lot since then, as have flash chips and SQL Compact (and SQLite).  SQLite may well be better on a Windows Phone - I know it's not on a Windows CE device where you can use direct table access - but a 10-year-old data point from different hardware, a substantially different platform and a significantly different version of the database engine is not helpful to the OP.